# Apply currency pipe when user type value inside input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe

I'm working in Angular 13 Project and reactive forms, I want to format an input amount while the user type the value, this is my current code:

```
  <input
    type="text"
    id="firstname"
    name="amount"
    formControlName="amount"
    [value]="productFormGroup.get('amount').value | currency:'EUR'"
  />
```

The value is formatted as I want but when I try to modify the value inside the input I got the following error:

```
preview-d88182ac6931a.js:2 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '1 500,00  is not a number' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'
```

Do you have any suggestions for the proper way to format the amount while user type value inside the input? I found a lot of articles about the topic but unfortunately there is no good approach suggested by Angular framework to format the amount properly when value change. I tried to set the property `pure: false` in a custom pipe but it doesn't work.

Comment: If it is only adding the currency name I suggest you use fixed prefix and suffix. Else if you want to listen to everykey stroke then you will probably need to add keyup event and use string.replace with regular expression to replace the original entered value by user and return the formatted version

Comment: @onrails thanks for your response. but i don't want to handle all these events by myself

Comment: ngneat input-mask mentioned below by @Drenai is the way to go then... There are similar libs on npm as well if you find it difficult to use. However it is easy and powerful

Comment: @onrails i found the library mentioned below very interesting, do you know how to change the position of the currency symbol? by default it on the left and i want to put it in the right

Answer (score 2):

The pipe expects a number, or a string that can be converted to a number. Once the input is converter to a string with currency symbol and comma it will no longer be valid input for the pipe

- https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

What you are trying to achieve is known as an [input mask](https://github.com/ngneat/input-mask)

Comment: thanks for your answer. is input-mask can work properly with reactive forms ?

Comment: Wow, I've never seen this library before. This is fantastic. Thanks for sharing!